# Shopify CLI, Shopify theme dev command taking me to error page

Tags: frontend, command-line-interface, shopify, shopify-cli

I was using this yesterday without this issue. Now, I try to 'login' to my shopify store from my terminal, and everything seems to work, then I can only see this error message and not my store.

I don't understand the terminal, Shopify CLI, etc. very well. Would love more insight into what is happened and what causes things to work or not work.

[This is the error message instead of showing the shopify store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF22q.png)

[This is my terminal where I'm using the shopify theme dev command in my Elizabeth folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKHOt.png)

/

I've tried restarting things. I tried going to brave browser because before it was Safari.

I will try more things but because I know so little I'm being proactive about asking so that I can get more insight. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the terminal command `shopify theme dev` produces a url that allows you to preview your theme locally. In the picture you've provided its the `http://127.0.0.1:9292` link. You can click on that url to view the theme from your browser.

The resource [shopify.dev](https://shopify.dev/) has more information about using Shopify's development tools.